# seg fault in very complicated (for me) program

Tags: c++, class, vector, iterator, segmentation-fault

i recently got my first "big" programming assignment. I had to design a poker game in c++. I've completed the program, it works just fine when using visual studio to compile, but when i brought it to the linux server my school uses, i get a seg fault.

I've narrowed down the seg fault to two functions one is posted on pastebin (linked), the other is below.

```
void deckOfCards::replaceCards(vector<card> &replaceHand, vector<int> cardsToReplace)
{
int removeThis;
for(int i=0;i<cardsToReplace.size();i++)
{
    replaceHand.push_back(dealCard());
}

while(cardsToReplace.size())
{
    removeThis=cardsToReplace[cardsToReplace.size()-1];//furthest index to be removed, so index      that erase needs to remove stays correct
    replaceHand.erase(replaceHand.begin()+removeThis);
    cardsToReplace.pop_back();
    }


}
```

here's the other function. http://pastebin.com/BiqJeHyR

Comment: You have narrowed it down to two functions, one of which you never posted? Well what if the error is in that function? If it is to long to post trying putting it on www.pastebin.com

Comment: I posted this one because they are written similarly, and both cause the problem. i commented out each of them and then both of them, if either one is called a seg fault occurs but i added the other function.

Comment: `cardsToReplace[cardsToReplace.size()]` is accessing elements outside the bounds of the container. Something like `cardsToReplace[cardsToReplace.size() - 1]` is likely more approparite. Make sure you check the side of the container to ensure it has 1 or more elements before accessing it like that.

Comment: `cardsToReplace[cardsToReplace.size()]` - Undefined behavior

Comment: Ah, I never understood they both caused the issue. My mistake.

Comment: Ah i actually had it with the -1 before, i was testing if that was causing the issue as i thought it needed the -1. turns out it  did, it wouldn't compile even in visual studio without the -1. with it though it still won't compile in g++

Comment: @Msd1994 `Ah i actually had it with the -1 before, i was testing if that was causing the issue as i thought it needed the -1. turns out it did` Please understand *why* the -1 was necessary, and not just use it because "it happened to work".

Comment: I do know why, because without it it would try to access one larger than the vector, for example if vector is size 5 it would be trying to access cardsToReplace[5] insteaad of cardsToReplace[4] which is the last index of the vector. I know how vectors work, not so much how iterators do though. would still like actual helpful answers instead of just telling me "go look up what vectors are." or similar replies please

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see with the code you posted is `cardsToReplace[cardsToReplace.size()]` is accessing elements outside the bounds of the container. This results in undefined behavior - is may crash, it might fail, or it can just appear to work as if everything is right in the Universe. Something like `cardsToReplace[cardsToReplace.size() - 1]` is more appropriate. You will want to make sure you check the size of the container to ensure it has 1 or more elements before accessing it like that otherwise you will end up with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If cardToReplace[i] > replaceHand.size() for any i, then that could cause problem since you are calling replaceHand.erase(replaceHand.begin() + cardToReplace[i]).

Comment: I don't believe it would ever be smaller, since the function using it ensures all the values in cardsToReplace are between 0 and 4.

the function passing in CardsToReplace uses a bool to check if the player would like to remove his cards, then checks if he would like to remove card 1, card 2, card 3, card 4, or card 5. if any are yes it passes in the card that is to be removed for each test. so the options would be either [0][1][2][3][4], [0][1][4], [1][4]... but nothing smaller than 0 or bigger than 4.